# How to store multiline input from user and print it in seperate lines?

Tags: python

I am noob in python please help out:
I am trying to make a program to remove spaces from a given string. You can initially provide how many number of sentences are there.
The code:

```
n=int(input("TestCases:"))#No of test cases

for i in range(0, n):
# read a string
    str = raw_input("Enter a string\n")
nospace = str.replace(" ", "")
print(nospace)
```

The output is:

```
TestCases:2
Enter a string
who am i
Enter a string
who are you
whoareyou
```

It is diplaying only the second test case.
I changed the code to:

```
n=int(input("TestCases:"))#No of test cases
for i in range(0, n):
# read a string
    str = raw_input("Enter a string\n")
    nospace = str.replace(" ", "")
    print(nospace)
```

But now the output is:

```
TestCases:2
Enter a string
who am i?
whoami?
Enter a string
who are you?
whoareyou?
```

Its printing out the string with characters removed as soon as its entered. My desired output is:

```
TestCases:2
Enter string(s)
who am i?
who are you?
whoami?
whoareyou?
```

I thought about storing the input as a list and displaying the output at each index, but can't seem to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is a minor change to your code that stores the string in a list and then iterates over that list to print the strings without spaces:

```py
n=int(input("TestCases:"))#No of test cases
string_list = []
for i in range(0, n):
# read a string
    string_list.append(raw_input("Enter a string\n"))
for str in string_list:
    nospace = str.replace(" ", "")
    print(nospace)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were absolutely correct in thinking a list is the way to go.

```
n=int(input("TestCases:"))#No of test cases
output = []

for i in range(0, n):
# read a string
    str = raw_input("Enter a string\n")
    nospace = str.replace(" ", "")
    output.append(nospace)

for i in output:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to replace a string part with some other string

```
string_part=" "
replace_with=''
str.replace(string_part,replace_with)
```

so in your condition

```
n=int(input("TestCases:"))#No of test cases
print("Enter s string\n")
for i in range(0, n):
    str = input("")
    nospace = str.replace(" ", "")
    print(nospace)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
TestCases:3
Enter s string
hi
hi
hello world
helloworld
hello hello world
hellohelloworld
```